# проблема комп.зрения

Tags: python, opencv

С чего начать?

есть дорожка с "фризами" (видео замерло) в видео, нужно, чтобы она посмотрела видео и исключила все фризы из него. могли бы направить, с чего подступиться, программировать умею, но с данным стеком плохо знаком.

Программа считывает данные из видео. Если программа находит отличия между текущим и предыдущим кадром, то она записывает его в видео.

пока сделал только это

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", help="path to the video file")
ap.add_argument("-a", "--min-area", type=int, default=500, help="minimum area size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

if args.get("video", None) is None:
    vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
    time.sleep(2.0)
# otherwise, we are reading from a video file
else:
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])


firstFrame = None #'data/videoForOpenCV.mp4'



while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = frame if args.get("video", None) is None else frame[1]
    text = "Unoccupied"

    if frame is None:
        break

    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
    if firstFrame is None:
        firstFrame = gray
        continue

    frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    for c in cnts:

        if cv2.contourArea(c) < args["min_area"]:
            continue

        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        text = "Occupied"

    cv2.imshow("Security Feed", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
    cv2.imshow("Frame Delta", frameDelta)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break
vs.stop() if args.get("video", None) is None else vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```